# Array-strings sorted using qSort in C

Tags: c, arrays, qsort

the question is simple: there is some way that the ordered array that returns me the "qsort", is returned in reverse, ie I want to avoid the use of any auxiliary array to invest the resulting array using qsort.

this is my code, which reads from standard input strings to be sorted, and uses a comparison function for sorting.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

            int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
            {
                const char **ia = (const char **)a;
                const char **ib = (const char **)b;
                return strcasecmp(*ia, *ib);
                /* strcmp functions works exactly as expected from
                comparison function */
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your response, sorry for my English

```
            int main (int argc, char *argv [])

            {
            int number;
            char temp [4000];

            printf("input number: ");
            scanf("%d",&number);

            char* array_string [number];
            int i;
            for (i=0;i<number;i++) {
            scanf(" %[^\n]", temp);
            array_string [i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(temp)+1)*sizeof(char));
            strcpy(array_string[i], temp);
            }


            size_t large = sizeof(array_string) / sizeof(char *);
            qsort(array_string,large ,sizeof(char *) ,cstring_cmp );
            printf ("\n");
            printf ("the sorted array list is:\n");
            for (i=0;i<large;i++)
            printf("%s\n", array_string [i]);
                    return 0;
            }
```

Comment: return -1 * strcasecmp(*ia, *ib); might work. If you reverse the comparison function the array will be reversed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
        int cstring_cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
        {
            const char **ia = (const char **)a;
            const char **ib = (const char **)b;
            return -strcasecmp(*ia, *ib);
            /* return the negative of the normal comparison */
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you just tried reversing the order of parameters to strcasecmp?

`return strcasecmp(*ib, *ia);`