# Test 2 stings for same words (C)

Tags: c, arrays, char

i am working on algorithm, that would compare two sentences and find if they are made of same words.

Basically the input of this function are 2 strings, i cut them by " " and each word put in array. So i have something like this:

```
sent1[0]="one"
sent1[1]="two"
sent1[2]="three"
sent1[3]="four"

sent2[0]="four"
sent2[1]="two"
sent2[2]="one"
sent2[3]="three"
```

My algoritm works that for each word from sent1 it compares each word in sent2.If the sentences are equal it return 1 , otherwise it return 0;

```
//n = max index of sent1 and m is max index of sent2


int equal =0;
for (i = 0; i < (n); i++){
     for (x = 0; x < (m); x++){
            if(strcmp(sent1[i],sent2[x])==0){
                equal =1;
            } 
     }
     if(equal==0){
         return 0;
     }
     equal=0;
}

return 1;
```

Problem of this algoritm is that it is very uneffective and slow, in order to make it faster it would be best to somehow delete index of array i already found equal word so every time i do new search it would search smaller array.Problem is that i dont know how to implement this in C because my every try ended with memory problems.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: When you find a match, you can use something very similar to the swap-and-pop idea. That'll effectively decrease the size of the arrays your searching.

Comment: Not trying an already-checked index won't give you a lot of speedup. With that, your algorithm is still `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061217/array-strings-sorted-using-qsort-in-c

Comment: Are you programming with bees?

Comment: As @kajacx said, sort and then compare 1 to 1, and your algorithm will be O(n) plus the sort that with an already made algorithm will be pretty fast.

Answer (score 0):

In C language you cannot delete an element from its array, because an C array a contiguous block of memory.
But you can shift left the elements after you "delete" an item.

However an another suggestion about your code:
When the 'strcmp' function success (found equal) then you no need continue the actual loop, you can terminate that with 'break' command.

```
int equal =0;
for (i = 0; i < (n); i++){
     for (x = 0; x < (m); x++){
            if(strcmp(sent1[i],sent2[x])==0){
                equal =1;
                break;
            } 
     }
     if(equal==0){
         return 0;
     }
     equal=0;
}

return 1;
```